# Image manipulation using ARM7TDMI

Tags: image, assembly, arm

Basically, I am separating the RGB values from each pixel(byte), getting the average, then setting the RGB values to this average. I am having problems loading the average colour into the two bits allocated to Red green and blue individually.

Comment: _"I am having problems"_ What problems exactly? What does your current code look like? In what way is it not working the way you expect it to?

Comment: Well I just don't know how to do it basically. I don't know how to leave the first two bits intacted(null), and alter the R,G and B values only. @Michael

Comment: Would I have to use an 'AND' operation? @Michael

Comment: You haven't described the pixel format and layout in your question.

Comment: b = (((p >> 0) & 0x3) + ((p >> 2) & 0x3) + ((p >> 4) & 0x3)) / 3; p = b | b << 2 | b << 4; ?

Comment: Well basically its a square image. I have found the image length and height, they are in registers. The pixel's are 1 byte each, laid out as follows: 0|0|R|R|G|G|B|B. I used individual masks(eg. 0x000000FF for Red), then got the average of RGB. Does that answer your question? @Michael